# Javascript - Update select input options with html contant

Tags: javascript, jquery, rendering

I am a really beginner in JS (I have work in IT since ... 15 years)
I use R/Shiny to create a web app (no mater, it should be the same with other languages).

My app render a select input with html values shown (some text and icons). That is good and render well. My HTML is simple:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>blabla</td>
      <td>bla bla</td>
      .....
</table>`
```

I am trying to use some javascript to update the content of the selected option/item with another HTML value. For example:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#sidebar_first_group .selectize-input')[0].textContent = "<table><tbody><tr><td>blou blou</td><td>bla bla</td>.....</table>"
```

The result is that the `input` is updated but the HTML is not interpreted, so the value that shows is the HTML code.

Have you any idea how to force the input to interpret and render the correct value?

Comment: Change `textContent` to `innerHTML` to set the content you assign to be rendered as HTML instead of text - although it sounds like you're trying to add a HTML table inside an `input` element, note that this is not possible.

Comment: Thanks Rory to have take some times to help me.
it was really a basic think, shame on me to haven't RTFM. 

I'm closed to finished what I want :) 
For information, I use selectize.js and I haven't notice that is very different from the default HTML select input. ( For the moment I can update the options list, the selected field is not updated well (should be the same issue). 
If i need help, i wil create a specific post for that in a Shiny/R context).

Thanks again